Django: Redirect to object's change (admin) page while overriding save_related
I am uploading a temporary file while changing my object, and this file might have problems which I can determine after it is fully read. I want my page to be redirected to the object's change page whenever an error occurs. here's the code I wrote:
    def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
        try:
            cleaned_data = form.cleaned_data
            if cleaned_data['file_field']:
                DEFAULT_COLUMN_INDEX = 0
                try:
                    # read file logic here that might raise an error
                    return super().save_related(request, form, formsets, change)
                except ValidationError as e:
                    messages.error(request, f"Error while proccessing data: {str(e)}")
                    redirection_url = reverse('admin:mymodel_change', args=[form.instance.id])
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(redirection_url)
        except TimeoutError as e:
            messages.error(request, f"Timeout in uploading file: {str(e)}")
            redirection_url = reverse('admin:mymodel_change', args=[form.instance.id])
            return HttpResponseRedirect(redirection_url)

Note that i can not just raise the error because it is set to response 500 because of other parts of the project (long story... i just cant change them!)
Here's my problem:
This code redirects to the mymodel admin page, not the change page of the object.
So, here's my questions:

Am i doing the right approach (since I'm new to django)?
If the approach's fine, how can i fix it?

UPDATE: 'admin:mymodel_change' is fine.

The problem basically is that save_related is not supposed to return a response, in fact the code that calls it does not even expect any return value.

You could try to leverage exceptions to perform the redirects like in this question but it would probably be better to improve the validation of your inlines so that the saving step is never reached at all. Trying to redirect on that step itself looks like abusing the functionality to me.

The issue is with your constructed URL for redirecting.
Instead of reverse('admin:mymodel_change', args=[form.instance.id]), you should use reverse('admin:yourappname_yourmodelname_change', args=[form.instance.id]), where yourappname is the name of your Django app and yourmodelname is the name of your model, so:
redirection_url = reverse('admin:yourappname_mymodel_change', args=[form.instance.id])


link's just fine, i have  printed it in logs (and got it from python manage.py show_urls). actually if i have entered the link incorrectly, i would've got 500 errror. aint I right?!

@rezaebrh If the link is correct and reverse('admin:mymodel_change', args=[form.instance.id]) is providing the correct URL to the change page of the object, then there might be another issue causing the redirection problem.
One possibility is that the super().save_related() method call might be overriding the redirection. Ensure that this method call is not causing any side effects that interfere with the redirection process. Additionally, make sure that there are no other middleware or decorators in your Django project that could be altering the behavior of the redirection.

@SunderamDubey save_related is actually not supposed to return any value.

@AbdulAzizBarkat No difference with or without return

@rezaebrh huh? Yes obviously. What I mean to say is that trying to use that method to change the response returned to the user is not going to work because the admin is not designed to handle that. You can do that but you'll have to override much more than just save_related to do that. Your attempt basically looks like a workaround to me though, you should instead focus on improving the validation on the inlines so you never reach this step at all.
